# Pull to Refresh on TableViewController when the tableView（ as the subview）at top or bottom state

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have four tableViews in UITableViewController,the UITableViewController is static type and only have one cell to contain that four tableviews.

When long touch up or touch down in the one of tableView, if the cell of tabview is top or down,I want to refresh the UITableViewController. But the event is handled by the tableView,how to pass the event to superview(UITableViewController?) when the condition is true.

Comment: I try to do it in subclass of Tableview,but it is not what i  wanted.
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return FALSE;
}

Comment: I think your approach needs some modifications. According to mine, you should use single UITableViewController that defaults with just one tableview. You can add sections in tableView. In your case, sections will be four. Now events can easily be handled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My sub-tableview is placed in one plane and separated by four quadrant.

Comment: Four quadrants could be handled by a UICollectionView. I agree with msmq that this situation is not a normal use, and without code and images, probably no one can answer.

Comment: @Tim and msmq thanks.